# RxJava 2 replay last item matching predicate?

Tags: rx-java2

How can I compose an operator like `replay` that replays the last item(s) matching a predicate, and then *all* future items?

For example, if a hot observable emits `A, B, C, D, E, F` and my predicate matches vowels, then a subscriber joining between `C` and `D` should receive `A, D, E, F`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only an egg, but here's what I came up with to replay a single item:

```
public static <T> Observable<T> replay(final Observable<T> observable,
                                final Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
    final AtomicReference<T> mLastMatch = new AtomicReference<>();
    return observable.map(e -> {
        if (predicate.test(e)) {
            mLastMatch.set(e);
        }
        return e;
    })
    .startWith(Observable.defer(() -> {
        final T t = mLastMatch.get();
        return t == null ? Observable.empty() : Observable.just(t);
    }));
}
```